# Java loop in a method asks for extra return statement

Tags: java, loops, return, boolean

I am trying to write a method that contains a for loop that loops through a string from the second digit to the end digit, checking to make sure that the characters in that part of the string are all digits.

```
public static boolean hasValidDigits (String nameAccount)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < nameAccount.length(); i++)
    {
        if(Character.isDigit(nameAccount.charAt(i)))
        {
        return true;
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }

    }
   (It keeps asking for an extra return statement here, I have no idea why)
}
```

I'm expecting the loop to run through the last 5 characters of a 6 character string check to make sure that they are digits and return true if they are, otherwise return false.

My problem is that the code keeps asking for an extra return statement that shouldn't be needed, also as far as results go when I add the extra return statement (just to get the code working) the boolean seems to work for only the starting digit in the string (changing the digit to another character returns false) but if I change any of the other digits further along the string it still returns true even though it should output false.

Any help on this or a push in the right direction would be a great help.

Comment: Well, if `nameAccount.length()` is 1 or 0, your loop is never iterated.  In that case, what should your method return?  And where would you put the `return` statement that tells the compiler what the method should return in that case?

Comment: Keep in mind that, if your loop is entered, it only checks a single `char` for both cases and immediately returns.

Comment: That's true.  This method stops after the first check, so it only ever checks the second digit.  Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method actually behaves as expected. *What a return statement does is to terminate a method immediately*. What's happening is: your method is not being run completely, it's being terminated prematurely. Try and follow the flow of your method; immediately after the first iteration, the entire method is terminated (with the return statement); so it never actually checks for the remaining characters. A better approach would be to do this:

```
public static boolean hasValidDigits(String nameAccount){
    for(int i = 0; i < nameAccount.length(); i++){
        if(!(Character.isDigit(nameAccount.charAt(i)))){
            return false;
           }
       }
       return true;
    }
```

This way, when looping, immediately the program encounters a character that is not a digit, the entire method is aborted and it returns false. However if no non-digit is detected, it means the String contains all digits and therefore, it returns true.

It's actually logical:

**Check for non-digits...
immediately one is detected, abort and return false...
If the iteration is complete and there is still no non-digit, return true!**

I hope this helps!

Merry coding!!!

Comment: That did the trick Taslim, thank you so much for that.And thank you everyone else for your input too.

Comment: start for from 1 or 0?

Comment: @Gholamali-Irani, I didn't see that.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider rewriting the method so that there is only one return statement. In this case it's not difficult to debug but if you had 30 execution paths as Matheus mentioned, it could be pretty tricky. You could also consider using regex here. As your code currently is, not all digits will be checked.

You can try regex at https://regex101.com/

at that point your method body could be something like

```
return yourString.matches(".\\d{5}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method needs an extra return statement to cover all possible paths of execution. Let's say your user inputs an empty string as its username. Your loop body would not be executed.

That's the reason Java is requiring an extra return statement.